# "bin/unpack200: not found" when installing TeamPostgreSQL

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. I downloaded the 68MB .sh file from [the project website](http://www.teampostgresql.com/download.jsp). When I run the file with sudo I get the following output:

```
ben@tardis:~$ sudo ./teampostgresql_ubuntu.sh 
Unpacking JRE ...
Preparing JRE ...
./teampostgresql_ubuntu.sh: 256: ./teampostgresql_ubuntu.sh: bin/unpack200: not found
Error unpacking jar files. Aborting.
You might need administrative priviledges for this operation.
```

I've tried installing `openjdk-7-jre-headless` but this didn't help. The project page doesn't list any dependencies so I'm not sure what to do from here. I've also tried running in a root shell, no difference.

Comment: You may have some more luck if you actually have an interactive root session instead of running the installer within sudo. `sudo su-` and then run the installer.

Comment: @HBruijn Tried that as well, no difference. :-(

Comment: Download the "cross-platform" version (on the download page), it runs without an installer.

Answer (score 7):

That is Package for 32bit system

If you use 64bit system then install 32bit libs

before ubuntu 13.10

> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

after ubuntu 14.04

> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386

for console mode

> teampostgresql_ubuntu.sh -c

Comment: Worked for me - thx for the tip @chozo00!